# Lost scope on page-object in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ckeditor

To store my webpage-contents I use multiple textareas depending on the number of languages. The id's/names of those textareas are content_nl, content_fr, content_en, ... depending on the number of languages we use (the forms are generated dynamically). I use ckeditor on every textarea.

To store the value I use vue.js with json. The values are stored in a page-object.

```
this.$http.put('/api/pages/' + this.pageId, this.page, function (response) {}
```

The content value in this.page is the value of the textarea and not of the editor. So I need to use the getData() function and then replace the content value per language in the this.page object (I don't know if that's a solid solution).

So before I used this:

```
if(CKEDITOR.instances.content_nl)
    this.page.translations['nl'].content = CKEDITOR.instances.content_nl.getData();

if(CKEDITOR.instances.content_en)
    this.page.translations['en'].content = CKEDITOR.instances.content_en.getData();
```

... (same for every language)

But I want it to be more reusable with any language possible so I use a function to generate an array with all languages on the page:

```
function getEditorLanguages()
{
    var collection = [];
    $('textarea.editor').each(function(){
        var data = this.id;
        var arr = data.split('_');
        collection.push(arr[1]);
    });

    return collection;
}
```

And then I try to replace the this.page.[language].content with the getData() value:

```
var collection = getEditorLanguages();
var self = this;
$.each(collection, function(index, value) {
    var field = 'content_nl' + value;
    if(CKEDITOR.instances.field)
        self.page.translations[value].content = CKEDITOR.instances.field.getData();
})
```

When entering the loop I lost the scope on my this.page object:

```
TypeError: this.page is undefined
```

How can I get to use that page-object in my loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a specific keyword which is related to the current context. Inside your loop, the current context are the `collection` elements and not what you intended.

You have to store the proper `this` object into a variable before use it.

```
var collection = getEditorLanguages();
var self = this;
$.each(collection, function(index, value) {
    if(CKEDITOR.instances.content_+value)
        self.page.translations[value].content = CKEDITOR.instances.content_+value.getData();
})
```

Comment: thx! Because the content_+value did not work I created a new variable var field = 'content_' + value and replace the two fieldnames in the if-statement by 'field'. But now I get a new TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.field is undefined

Comment: @BFlyDesign I am sorry but I do not know much about CKEditor. Maybe should you open a new question. But the error is quite explicit: these objets to not have any `field` attribute. This probably means that you do not use it as intended, but I really can not help you much, sorry.